# Doctrine geberated entities, broken vars and relations, Doctrine 2 and zf2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have an old MySQL database. Somehow I have managed to generate the entities from the command line, however the results differ from what I was expecting.

After generation it has removed the `_` from my my table and field names; such as this class:

```
namespace CMS\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * Countries
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Countries")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Countries
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pa_CountryID", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $paCountryid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="t_CountryName", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $tCountryname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="t_MapAbr", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $tMapabr;


    /**
     * Get paCountryid
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPaCountryid()
    {
        return $this->paCountryid;
    }

    /**
     * Set tCountryname
     *
     * @param string $tCountryname
     * @return Countries
     */
    public function setTCountryname($tCountryname)
    {
        $this->tCountryname = $tCountryname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tCountryname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTCountryname()
    {
        return $this->tCountryname;
    }

    /**
     * Set tMapabr
     *
     * @param string $tMapabr
     * @return Countries
     */
    public function setTMapabr($tMapabr)
    {
        $this->tMapabr = $tMapabr;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tMapabr
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTMapabr()
    {
        return $this->tMapabr;
    }
}
```

My questions:

- How do I generate the entities with *exactly* the same table and fields names?
- If I have another entity that uses `pa_CountryID` as a foreign key; How do I make the relation between them to populate them with one step?

My other entity looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace CMS\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * LoginUsers
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Login_Users", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fulltext", columns={"pt_userName", "t_firstName", "t_lasName"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class LoginUsers
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pa_userID", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $paUserid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pt_userName", type="string", length=50, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $ptUsername;


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="i_CountryID", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $iCountryid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

> How do I generate the entities with exactly the same table and fields names?

I think you are wrong. All fields names are ok. Look at annotations

```
/**
 * ...
 * @ORM\Column(name="pa_userID", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 * ...
 */
private $paUserid;
```

You have class attribute `$paUserid`, but ORM Column name is `pa_userID`. So attributes with no '_'  are mapped correct. And this is a Symfony naming convention.

2.

> If I have another entity that uses pa_CountryID as a foreign key; How do I make the relation between them to populate them with one step?

As I mentioned column names are ok. So your relations are safe. Now to make relations beetween tables you should read [Database & Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations) and [Doctrine Associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

In big shourtcut - how to set relation between LoginUsers and Countries. Now LoginUsers::$iCountryid will be a country OBJECT, not an id. In database you will find id ofcourse.

```
// ...
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
// ...
class Countries
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\CMS\Entity\LoginUsers", mappedBy="iCountryid")
     */
    private $loginUsers;
    // ...
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->loginUsers = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

class LoginUsers
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @var \CMS\Entity\Countries
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\CMS\Entity\Countries", inversedBy="loginUsers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="i_CountryID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $iCountryid;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, i am new into Zend technologie and Doctrine, that was a nice example, but i still got a problem about the linking, the result i got after read it and applying this solution, for example the country ID i have for the records is 117, but it is getting the object with id 234 i checked the queries but no join applied in the sql. was searching why the mapping always taking the last row in the database or the results set not the exact  one?

Comment: Oh, i did the following removed the code from Countries Class on construct, because every user has 1 country only, the fixed the mapping in the loginusers class from: @ORM\JoinColumn(name="i_CountryID", referencedColumnName="id") to: * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="i_CountryID", referencedColumnName="pa_CountryID") and bingo got the right country :), all the relations i have in my table Parent---> got multiple sutff but some not. i guess i'll learn more about it when i work with it., thats an Accepted Answer :) thank you again

Answer (score 0):

The "name" attribute from @ORM\Table and @ORM\Column represent the table and field names in your database, nothing changed , except that when you interact with the PHP objects it will be without the underscores